# Connecting MySQL to C++ Console Application and simple login system

Tags: c++, mysql, authentication

I'd like to make simple login system in C++ Console Application with MySQL, and if login details are correct, it should execute my actual code.

How can that be done?

If possible, i'd also like to add so, when user login's for the first time, to store his HWID in database so no one else can login with same login credentials.

Thanks in advance, I am new to C++ programming and I don't really know what should I do:)

Comment: Start with the official example programs: [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html) work with these for a few days before you continue.

Comment: ***I am new to C++ programming*** It's probably months before you should be doing a  project like this. You should have a good understanding of `c++` before trying to connect to a database.

Comment: but can't you give me some example for what I asked..?

Comment: I know some basics I just want to learn how does this what I asked works. thats it

Comment: As a beginner, I would recommend that you use `std::vector` for the data and `std::map` for the index tables.  When you get that working and feel comfortable, then expand to use MySQL.  Getting MySQL to build and the interface working is frustrating even for the most advanced C++ programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of a login system:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

struct Login_Info
{
    string name;
    unsigned int  id;
};

int main()
{
    vector<Login_Info> user_database;
    string user_name;
    cout << "Enter User's name:";
    getline(cout, user_name);
    unsigned int user_id = 0U;
    cout << "\nEnter User's ID: ";
    cin >> user_id;
    Login_Info user_info;
    user_info.name = user_name;
    user_info.id   = user_id;
    // Insert the User's info into the database.
    user_database.push_back(user_info);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Searching and comparing are left as an exercise for the OP or Reader.

**Edit 1: Index tables**
Let's move the info I/O into the `struct`, then focus on building the database.

```
struct Login_Info
{
    string       name;
    unsigned int id;
    void  input_from_console(std::ostream& console_output_stream,
                             std::istream& console_input_stream);
};

void Login_Info::input_from_console(std::ostream& console_stream)
{
    console_output_stream << "Enter User's name: ";
    getline(console_input_stream, name);
    if (name.empty())
    {
        id = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        console_output_stream << "\nEnter User ID: ";
        console_input_stream >> id;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<Login_Info> user_database;
    std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int> index_by_id;
    Login_Info         user_info;
    while (true)
    {
        user_info.input_from_console(cout, cin);
        if (user_info.name.empty())
        {
            break;
        }
        unsigned int vector_index = user_database.size();
        user_database.push_back(user_info);  
        index_by_id[user_info.id] = vector_index;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The above program builds a database using `std::vector`, and creates an index table using `std::map`.

The User's name with ID == 5, can be found by:

```
Login_Info user_info;
const unsigned int vector_index = index_by_id[5];
user_info = database[vector_index];  
cout << "User #5 is: " << user_info.name << "\n";
```